# Bootstrap Source Code vs Bootstrap CDN Link

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm revamping the UI for my website which uses Bootstrap 5.3. I originally built it using the CDN link the official documentation provides. I've recently purchased Bootstrap Studio as a tool to help me build the UI.

The problem is that I can only export my project with the Bootstrap CSS included in a minified file. Can I continue to use the CDN links or am I forced to remove the CDN links and use the bootstrap.min.css files Bootstrap Studio provides? Is there a de-facto standard that I'm not following?

I've tried only using the CDN links and it seems to break my site since I previously used a legacy version. I'd prefer using the official CDN links than the CSS files I was provided so that I can use the built in libraries they provide.

Answer (score 0):

When you export your project you have an option to check "Use CDN for Librairies".

Source: https://bootstrapstudio.io/docs/exporting.html#export-settings

Comment: I know it says that, but it doesn't provide the CDN libraries which is why I'm confused.